# How to recover funds from ETH address generated using Bitcoin xpub?

Tags: addresses, bitcoin, recovery

By accident I generated ETH address using Bitcoin xpub. Is there any way to recover funds from that ETH address?

Answer (score 1):

No, The algo use for Bitcoin is not the same as Ethereum so your key would not generate the same result.

Bitcoin uses the SHA-256 and secp256k1 algorithms, while Ethereum uses Keccak-256 and the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA).